# In Qt, lambda Expression not able to invoked slot([this] () mutable {QTimer::SingleSlot(200,this,SLOT(DataReceived())); }

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to capture serial data using **QTimer::SingleShot** in lambda expression.When **&QSerialPort::readyRead** Signal is received then in lambda expression i am stating a single shoot timer to invoke the Main Window Slot but it didn't work.

Can i use lambda like this or not?

> connect(cHandler->tSerial,&QSerialPort::readyRead,this, [this] mutable {QTimer::singleShot(200,this,SLOT(DataReceived()));  } );

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>
#include "comm.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
     comm *cHandler;
     MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
     uint8_t countReq;
     QTimer *rTime;
private:
     Ui::MainWindow *ui;
public slots:
   void QueryMethod(bool);
   void excRequest();
   void DataReceived();
   void ReceivedDataAndUpdateGUi(QByteArray);
   void SerialPortRadioCallBack (bool);
   void TcpIpRadioCallBack      (bool);
   void TcpIpClientRadioCallBack(bool);
   void TcpIpServerRadioCallBack(bool);
   void SwitchCommType();
   void TcpIpServerListenCallBack(bool);
   void TcpIpClientConnectCallBack(bool);
   void RefreshSerialPortCallBack(bool);
   void ConnectSerialPortCallBack(bool);
 };
 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp [some code]

```
void MainWindow::ConnectSerialPortCallBack (bool)
{
   if( ui->ConnectSerialPortButton->text() == "Open")
   {
    try {
        QSerialSett SerialConfig = {
            ui->PortComboBox->currentText(),
            static_cast <QSerialPort::BaudRate>(ui->BaudComboBox->currentText().toUInt()),
            static_cast <QSerialPort::DataBits>(ui->DataBitsComboBox->currentIndex()+5),
            static_cast <QSerialPort::StopBits>(ui->StopBitsComboBox->currentIndex()),
            static_cast <QSerialPort::Parity>  (ui->ParityComboBox->currentIndex()),
            QSerialPort::NoFlowControl
        };
        cHandler->tSerial = new portComm(this,SerialConfig);
        connect(cHandler->tSerial,&QSerialPort::readyRead,this, [this]() mutable {QTimer::singleShot(200,this,SLOT(DataReceived()));  } ); //qDebug() <<cHandler->tSerial.readAll(); print correct data here
        cHandler->setLastSessionType(BS_SERIAL_TYPE);
        ui->ConnectSerialPortButton->setText("Connected");
        ui->ConnectSerialPortButton->setStyleSheet("background-color:green; color:white;");
    } catch (...) {
        qDebug() << "SERIAL PORT ERROR !";
    }
   }
 else
   {
    cHandler->tSerial-> close();
    delete  cHandler->tSerial;
    qDebug() << "SERIAL PORT CLOSED ::";
    cHandler->setLastSessionType(BS_NO_TYPE);
    ui->ConnectSerialPortButton->setText("Open");
    ui->ConnectSerialPortButton->setStyleSheet("background-color:red; color:white;");

   }
}

void MainWindow::DataReceived()
{
cHandler->tSerial->readAll();
}
```

Comment: Did you try the new syntax (&MainWindow::DataReceived) with the QTimer?

Comment: QTimer::singleShot(200,this,&MainWindow::DataReceived); thank you so much ,its working fine.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld can you please tell me why SLOT(DataReceived()) not worked.

Comment: @bhura Is DataReceived a slot?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes DataReceived is a slot, i already mention in my question